# Hosting a WCF service using Window Service using a non-local host domain

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I would like to host internet based net-tcp WCF service through window service rather than IIS?
What I want to know is, is it possible for the end point URI to be something other than non-localhost domain based URI.
So for e.g. I would like to access the service at `<http://dev1/myservice>` rather than a standard `<http://localhost:90/myservice`> which is what almost all the documented examples mention.
Is what I'm trying to do even possible with hosting using a window service in mind (obviously with IIS hosting, I know it's possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. I made a windows service with WCF service self hosted and it's running in production enviroment.
This is my service onfiguration section

```
<service
          name="WinService.Comunication.ExecutionService" behaviorConfiguration="ExecutionServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="WinService.Comunication.IExecutionService"
                  bindingConfiguration="binding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://vm-adminHost:11485/ExecutionService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

It is working fine. Your client app must resolve your server name.

Comment: Ok so if I already had a DNS resolution setup previously for http://dev1 to resolve to a specific internal server IP, I should be ok?

Comment: Was my answer useful for you?